# Hair particles are not fitting my fractal ground

Tags: particles

I created an object composed of 6 different forms and I want it to simulate grasses and my plane that contains "mountains" and a generally altered surface (so its not a plane any more ^^).

When coming to add particles, my object does not fit the ground. If I use rotation and altered my Y axis object, I don’t have a pretty natural result, and nothing is sitting on my floor...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you show where the object's origins are?

Comment: Are there any modifiers on the plane?  Try checking *Use Modifier Stack*.

Comment: I Carlo ! and thanks. I set the origin in the center of the geometry you see on the right panel in my image above.

Comment: And i have no modifier on the plane except the one for the particles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Set Random velocity to 0

As state by the [Blender manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/introduction.html#velocity) about the option:

> Gives the starting speed a random variation

Each object, having a different emission speed, is found at a different distance from the surface at the current frame (even if it is the staring one).

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Well thanks for the tips, it really helps. You made my day :) Thanks again !