# Particles should be on ground

Tags: particles

[image: The grass is in the air]
I need it to be on the ground. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you add a sample blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?, there is currently not enough info to determine what your problem is.

Comment: Alternatively, see if https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63991/hair-particle-system-to-create-forest-some-trees-are-floating?rq=1 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/hair-particles-are-not-fitting-my-fractal-ground?rq=1 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/why-are-the-objects-in-my-hair-particle-system-not-sitting-on-top-of-the-ground?rq=1 help.

Comment: Turn off Particle children

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure the object you want as your particle is facing straight up to the z axis. Then snap it or move it to the center of the grid in the cursor's world origin. That will draw everything in to the emitter to emit perfectly.