# problem with making grass?

Tags: mesh

I am beginner in blender.
I want to make grass. but I want to put all parts of grass on the soil . but I can not.
how to do it?
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/why-are-the-objects-in-my-hair-particle-system-not-sitting-on-top-of-the-ground https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/hair-particles-are-not-fitting-my-fractal-ground https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63991/hair-particle-system-to-create-forest-some-trees-are-floating

Comment: what i usually do is to go into edit mode and rotate or move the emitted object till the objects that are emitted are in the right position and rotation.